# Typoscript including php file to the main container TYPO3

Tags: php, include, typo3, containers, typoscript

I am including a php file via typoscript to a specific page. Its all working fine but I want to add this file to the main container.

Here is the typoscript:

```
page = PAGE
page.10 = USER_INT
page.10 {
includeLibs =  fileadmin/php/shop_init.php
userFunc = voucher->init

}
```

Where I can define that the return element show in the main container?

Comment: Can you please post the code from the PHP file? Do you have a return value?

Comment: yes it returns the right code back but its rendering the code right after the body tag. i want to include file in the main container of the page.

<?php
class voucher {
public function init(){
//code
return $value;
}
}

Comment: Please provide the TypoScript configuration for your main template.